# Determine the order of entire function $G(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n!)^\alpha}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let
$$G(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n!)^\alpha}$$
for $\alpha>0$. Prove that it's an entire function and determine its order. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Try proving that the power series converges everywhere to prove it's entire. What do you mean by order? This? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type

Comment: @Ilham: Yes it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Entire" means that it is holomorphic on the whole complex plane. This means, in your case, that you must show that the convergence radius is $\infty$. But this is $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \space \frac 1 {\frac 1 {(n+1)^\alpha}} = \infty$, as wanted.

The order is given by $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \space \frac {n \log n} {- \log \frac 1 {n!^\alpha}} = \frac 1 \alpha \frac {n \log n} {\log n!} = \frac 1 \alpha$.

To show that $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \space \frac {n \log n} {\log n!} = 1$ use [the theorem of Stolz-Cesaro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem): you get $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \space \frac {(n+1) \log(n+1) - n \log(n)} {\log(n+1)} = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \space \frac {\log (\frac {n+1} n)^n + \log (n+1)} {\log (n+1)}$ and $(\frac {n+1} n)^n \to \mathbb{e}$.

Comment: Thanks. Why in the $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \space \frac {n \log n} {- \log \frac 1 {n!^\alpha}}$, the denominator has minus sign?

Comment: @Mark: That's from the general formula; if you take one more look at the definition of the order from the link given above by Ilham, you will see that for a function $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$ the order is given by $\limsup \frac {n \log n} {- \log |a_n|}$. In your case, since $a_n$ is convergent, $\limsup$ gets replaced by a usual $\lim$.

Comment: ok, it is clear. Thank you!